# Creating a test for a method in Java DAO class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

For the following Java class DAO I created in InteliJ, I need to create a test that:

"Returns two reservations for test parkId 1."

I need help with writing the logic itself for a possible test

Here is the method:

```
@Override
public List<UpcomingReservation> getAllUpcomingReservations() {
    List<UpcomingReservation> reservations = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE from_date >= CURRENT_DATE AND from_date <= CURRENT_DATE + 30";
    SqlRowSet results = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(sql);
    while (results.next()) {
        reservations.add(mapRowToUpcomingReservation(results));
    }
    return reservations;
}
```

Comment: Where does the `parkId` come in in your code? I see no logic there around the `parkId` concept.

Comment: This is a project with multiple DAO methods that are connected to SQL tables. Will it help if I provide the logic for Park DAO and the table columns for Park?

Comment: No, not really. You wrote `"Returns two reservations for test parkId 1."` and my question is where is this `parkId` relevant in the code you showed? I see nothing using an ID. I could provide you with a test for the method but I am not understanding your statement.

Comment: Yes, I apologize. I wrote the Select statement incorrectly. I was supposed to join 4 tables, one of them was a park table. I was able to come up with the test for this one for now. Thank you for your follow up.

Comment: Then please write an answer of how you did it and accept it as the correct answer so that others may benefit from it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The correct SQL query was supposed to be as follows which would have included the parkID:

```
}
public List<Reservation> getAllReservationsNext30Days(int parkID) {
    List<Reservation> reservations = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM park JOIN campground ON park.park_id = campground.park_id JOIN site ON campground.campground_id = site.campground_id JOIN reservation ON site.site_id = reservation.site_id WHERE from_date >= CURRENT_DATE AND from_date <= CURRENT_DATE + 30";
    SqlRowSet results = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(sql);
    while (results.next()) {
        reservations.add(mapRowToReservation(results));
    }
    return reservations;
}
```

And the correct test I was trying to create was:

```
@Test
public void getUpcomingReservations_Should_ReturnNext30DayReservations(){
    List<Reservation> upcomingReservation = dao.getAllReservationsNext30Days(1);
    assertEquals(2, upcomingReservation.size());
}
```